# How do ggplot stat_* functions work conceptually?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently trying to get my head around the differences between `stat_*` and `geom_*`  in `ggplot2`.  (Please note this is more of an interest/understanding based question than a specific problem I am trying solve).

### Introduction

My current understanding is that is that the `stat_*` functions apply a transformation to your data and that the result is then passed onto the `geom_*` to be displayed.

Most simple example being the identity transformation which simply passes your data untransformed onto the geom.

```
ggplot(data = iris) + 
    stat_identity(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width) , geom= "point")
```

More practical use-cases appear to be when you want to use some transformation and supply the results to a non-default geom, for example if you wanted to plot an error bar of the 1st and 3rd quartile you could do something like:

```
ggplot(data = iris) + 
    stat_boxplot(aes(x=Species, y = Sepal.Length, ymax = ..upper.., ymin = ..lower..), geom = "errorbar")
```

### Question 1

So how / when are these transformations applied to the dataset and how does data pass through them exactly?

As an example, say I wanted to take the `stat_boxplot` transformation and plot the point of the 3rd quartile how would I do this ?

My intuition would be something like :

```
ggplot(data = iris) + 
    stat_boxplot(aes(x=Species, y = ..upper..) , geom = "point")
```

or

```
ggplot(data = iris) + 
    stat_boxplot(aes(x=Species, y = Sepal.Length) , geom = "point")
```

however both error with

```
Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

My guess is as part of the `stat_boxplot` transformation it consumes the y aesthetic and produces a dataset not containing any `y` variable however this leads onto ....

### Question 2

Where can I find out which variables are consumed as part of the `stat_*` transformation and what variables they output? Maybe i'm looking in the wrong places but the documentation does not seem clear to me at all...

Comment: I can't test right now but I believe you need to call geom_point and pass stat_boxplot to its stat argument. The reason is that you need to pass x and y to the aes of geom_point and your approach passes them to the aes of stat_boxplot.

Comment: I don't think that will make a difference sorry,  because both `stat_*` and `geom_*`  are just wrappers for  the `layer()` function but with fixed values for the `stat` and `geom` arguments.  So I think just shifting to `geom_point()` will still result in the same call to `layer()`.  Thank you for your comment though !

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: I did - `ggplot(data = iris) + geom_point( aes(x=Species, y = Sepal.Length), stat = "boxplot")`   results in the same error message `Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: y`  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting questions...

As background info, you can read [this chapter](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html#statistical-transformations) of R for Data Science, focusing on the grammar of graphics. I'm sure Hadley Wickham's [book on ggplot2](http://amzn.to/2ef1eWp) is even a better source, but I don't have that one.

The main steps for building a graph with one layer and no facet are:

1. Apply aesthetics mapping on input data (in simple cases, this is a selection and renaming on columns)
2. Apply scale transformation (if any) on each data column
3. Compute stat on each data group (i.e. per Species in this case)
4. Apply aesthetics mapping on stat data, detected with `..<name>..` or `stat(name)`
5. Apply position adjustment
6. Build graphical objects
7. Apply coordinate transformations

As you guessed, the behaviour at step 3 is similar to `dplyr::transmute()`: it consumes all aesthetics columns and outputs a data frame having as columns all freshly computed stats and all columns that are constant within the group. The stat output may also have a different number of rows from its input. Thus indeed in your example the `y` column isn't passed to the geom.

To do this, we'd like to specify different mappings at step 1 (before stat) and at step 4 (before geom). I thought something like this would work:

```
# This does not work:
ggplot(data = iris) + 
  geom_point(
    aes(x=Species, y=stat(upper)), 
    stat=stat_boxplot(aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) )
```

...  but it doesn't (stat must be a string or a Stat object, but stat_boxplot actually returns a Layer object, like geom_point does).

NB: `stat(upper)` is an equivalent, more recent, notation to your `..upper..`

I might be wrong but I don't think there is a way of doing this directly within ggplot. What you can do is extract the stat part of the process above and manage it yourself before entering ggplot():

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  select(y=Sepal.Length) %>% 
  do(StatBoxplot$compute_group(.)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Species, upper)) + geom_point()
```

A bit less elegant, I admit...

For your question 2, it's in the doc: see sections Aesthetics and Computed variables of `?stat_boxplot`

Comment: @gowerc, is it the type of answer you were expecting?